# What is the meaning of ('0001') in default contraint of a datetimeoffset field?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

One of my table definitions shows as:

[image]

What is the meaning of '0001' as default value for a datetimeoffset column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0001` is the date specified in *unseparated* [string literal format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#supported-string-literal-formats-for-date) (`yyyy[mmdd]`). It corresponds to `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00`, the smallest value for the [`datetimeoffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) data type.

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to "teach a person to fish", here's how you could determine this *posteriori*:

```sql
select cast('0001' as datetimeoffset(7));
```

That is, take the value of the default constraint and cast it to the data type of the column to which the default applies.